# No transition on first form

Tags: codenameone

I am using a CN1 project created by the CN1 plugin in IntelliJ.  I have built a form by hand (not using the GUI builder).  I would like the first form shown to be my form.  Unfortunately, it seems to bootstrap code that loads the theme expects me to use a form created in the GUI builder.  In fact, when my application loads, it briefly shows the default Hello World screen, and then transitions to my form by scrolling the form from right to left.  How do I make my hand-coded form the first thing on the screen appear without any transition?

It would seem that I could just override StateMachine.getFirstFormName(), but my form is not known to the underlying code.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this... Try creating a new project with Get Started template selected.

Open **MyApplication.java** or any other name you changed `MyApplication` to. Replace the `hi form` code and use this as your code foundation.